# Does not show the array passed from controller in view

Tags: arrays, codeigniter

I have an array in a function in my controller.I passed this array to a view and wanted to show this array in a select tag.But it does not show any thing and any error.
controller

```
function get_user($user_id) {
$data['rec']=$this->amodel->all_data('user_id');
foreach($data['rec'] as $i )
{
$data1['name']=$this->amodel->get_role_name($i->role_id);
}
$this->load->view('edit_user',array_merge($data,$data1));
}
```

I used `var_dump()` to print the array and it returned 4 records.
view

```
<?php foreach($rec->resutl as $row) {?>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $row->username ?>" name="username">
<select name="role">
<?php foreach($name->result() as $n ) {?>
<option value="<?php echo $n->role_id ?>"><?php echo $n->name  ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
<?php } ?>
```

in second `foreach()` does not show any thing.I could not find the problem.
plz help me.

Comment: So you can see the 4 input text but not the select options ?

Comment: please let us see the array that you are getting in the view..

Comment: Is it normal that you call a function in your second array ? You type : $name->result(), maybe it's just $name->result

Comment: @AmirBawab those 4 records are the 4 options which I want to display them in select tag

Comment: @setara but I mean you have 2 nested foreach loops, the first one display the `<input type="text" value="<?php echo $row->username ?>" name="username">` and the second one displays the `options`. Does the first foreach execute, in other words, does it show the `<input type="text" value="<?php echo $row->username ?>" name="username">` ?

Comment: @VincentDecaux yes it is correct.Because I return the `$query` not `$query->result()` from model to controller.

Comment: @AmirBawab yes the first foreach works correctly

Comment: Just weird in MVC I think, model should return data, not queries, but anyway, you should firslty var_dump($name->result()); and see if you have results :)

Comment: @setara Can you print_r($name->result()); in the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you print both arrays?
Here you are merging two arrays and then passing to view so first check or print both arrays.
Also foreach($name->result() as $n ) here may be the problem $name->result()

Comment: thanks the problem was with `$name->result()`. I remove `result()`